Opencart 4 issues with total
I am looking for someone with experience in OpenCart 4 and PHP. I am facing an issue where, in the admin panel under Sales -> Orders, the total amount is displayed correctly for orders with the currency in EUR. However, for orders with the currency in USD, the total is always displayed as zero. For all order statuses in EUR total is correct, but for dollars issue exists.
Looking for some advice or possible solutions. Maybe someone has faced the same issue before.
The issue exists in all OpenCart4 versions.


are you sure the USD currency value is set correct
